# angular login with ui-router can't redirect to login page

Tags: angularjs

I create a login module for my website like:

```
angular.module('caknow', [
  'ui.router',
  'ngStorage',
  'authentication',
  'login'
])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('index', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '../template/dashboard/dashboard.html'
      })
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: '../template/authen/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
      });
  }])
  .run(['$location', '$http', 'tokenSer', '$state', '$rootScope', function($location, $http, tokenSer, $state, $rootScope) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['x-api-key'] = '*********';
    var token = tokenSer.get(); // service to get token store in localStorage.
    if (token) {
      $http.defaults.headers.common['x-access-token'] = 'token';
    }

    console.log("hello world");
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){
      if ($location.path() != '/login' && !token) {
          console.log("hello world login");
        $state.go('login');
      }
    });
  }])
```

The main page like:

```
  <BODY ng-app="caknow">
    <div ui-view></div>
  </BODY>
```

For `index` state, I want main page load dashboard.html template.
For `login` state, I want main page load login.html template.
If user doesn't login and get a token from server, user will be redirected to `login` state. But, when I use http-server to start a server and try to access `localhost:port` at first time. I don't redirect to login page and show a white page. In my opinion, I find that `$stateChangeStart` doesn't emit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prevent the default event so you can start another:

`event.preventDefault();`

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){
    if ($location.path() != '/login' && !token) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I see that the $stateChangeStart even is emitted infinitely

Comment: You could try adding it into $stateChangeSuccess and see if that works?